# Placement of nicht to negative nebensatz

Tags: grammar-identification, negation

> Meiner Meinung nach bedeutet diese Aussage, nicht dass alle der Informationen zu einem Thema durch ein Bild erklärt werden,
>
> Meiner Meinung nach bedeutet diese Aussage  nicht, dass alle der Informationen zu einem Thema durch ein Bild erklärt  werden, (correct)

My native corrected my sentence (first one) to the second one. My question is simply, why do we keep nicht in the Hauptsatz rather than the beginning of the Nebensatz?

Comment: I don't consider this question as simple, especially since you give no reason for  the negation being part of the clause, which is negated in total.

Comment: What clause did you intend to negate, the main clause or the subordinate clause?

Comment: Shouldn't that read `... dass alle Informationen ..`, or `... dass all die Informationen ...`?

Comment: Where is the finite verb in the dass-Nebensatz? Looks like the end is missing. Could you cite the fulll sentence?

Comment: Du könntest auch sagen: "Meiner Meinung nach bedeutet diese Aussage, dass nicht alle der Informationen zu einem Thema ...". Im Einzelfall kann aber ein semantisch subtiler Unterschied bestehen, weil die Abwesenheit einer Bedeutung nicht immer die Abwesenheit bedeutet. Beispiel: "Diese Aussage bedeutet nicht, dass a größer 3 ist." vs. "Diese Aussage bedeutet, dass a nicht größer als 3 ist." Die Aussage lässt vielleicht offen, ob a > 3 ist, z.B. könnte a=Wurzel(16) sein, und also 4 oder -4; anderswo könnte es weitere Informationen zu a geben, die mit in die Betrachtung gezogen werden müssen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, clauses are fairly self-contained in German, so adverbs go in the same clause as the verb they modify. In this case *nicht* modifies *bedeuten* so they belong in the same clause. Of course if the intended meaning is different, and you're really trying to negate *alle Informationen*, then *nicht* would go in front of it, since *nicht* usually goes in front of what is being negated if it's not a verb. Even in that case, you wouldn't start the clause with *nicht*; a *dass* clause starts with *dass*.

Answer (score 1):

Frage:

> Why do we keep 'nicht' in the Hauptsatz rather than the beginning of the Nebensatz?

Beispiel:

> Meiner Meinung nach bedeutet diese Aussage nicht, dass alle der Informationen zu einem Thema durch ein Bild erklärt werden

Das Wort "Nicht" steht bei einfachen Zeitformen am Satzende, bei zusammengesetzten Zeitformen vor dem Vollverb am Satzende. [1](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau/verneinung)

Beispiele:

> Er schläft nicht.

> Er hat gestern Nacht nicht geschlafen.

Comment: Just so you know, the custom here is answer questions in the language they were asked if possible. We don't expect you to answer in a language if you don't speak it well enough, but we try to answer in the language the person asking the question is most familiar with.